# Where main method is creating in my web application if i use struts or servlet or spring

Tags: java

Hi if I develop any web application where is main method will created to execute my all java classes.If I use struts frame work or spring or servlets.

Comment: @sᴜʀᴇsʜᴀᴛᴛᴀ - I don't think so ...

Comment: Agreed. That question has been asked in a different manner ,and end up with same answer :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For a typical Java webapp, the `main` method is *typically* implemented by the web container that you use to run your webapp.

That covers the "structs" and "servlets" case.  And also Spring MVC.

But in the case of Spring *in general*, it is probably not possible to give a concrete answer.  (For instance, Spring core can be used in a wider range of contexts than just "webapp" development.)

Comment: If i give concurrent request will my web app will create new thread of execution in web continer thank u.

Comment: @Venkataramareddy - It will probably use / reuse an existing thread from the container's worker thread pool.  (Creating new Java threads is relatively expensive.)

Answer (score 3):

Struts, spring, or any other framework play no role in your question because they end up as a part of your web application, which is itself just an archive file which gets *deployed* into a Web application container. It is that *container* which is a Java application containing its `main` method.

You shall never see, or need to see, or want to see, that `main` method because it doesn't contain anything of interest to you as the Web application developer.

Answer (score 0):

We use **web.xml** to control web application. main() method has no significance in java web application.